# arithmetic left shift 30 times in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
2<<2 === Math.pow(2,3) // true
2<<30 === Math.pow(2, 31) // false, why?
```

I think Math.pow was same with <<;
why `Math.pow(2, 31)` not equal `2<<30` ?

Comment: What question are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your original question, "Why does 2 << 30 equal -2,147,483,648?"

The `<<` is the bit shift left operator, so `2 << 30` means "shift the value 2 to the left by 30 bits".

The value 2 as a 32-bit integer is:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
```

If you shift all bits to the left by 30 spaces, you have:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This value is -2,147,483,648 because the MSB (most significant bit) is the sign bit, which makes the number negative. This is because your computer uses [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) arithmetic.